# Permission denied errors when listening on HTTPS ports with ring on Heroku

Tags: ssl, heroku, clojure, jetty, ring

Following the accepted answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33037973/2023432), I generated a keystore with the command `keytool -keystore keystore.jks -genkey -alias server` and committed it to source control in the `resources` folder of my project. Then, I set up the server to use that keystore.

#### src/clj/foo/server.clj

```
(ns foo.server
  (:require [foo.handler :refer [app]]
            [config.core :refer [env]]
            [ring.adapter.jetty :refer [run-jetty]])
  (:gen-class))

 (defn -main [& args]
   (let [port (Integer/parseInt (or (env :port) "3000"))]
     (run-jetty app {:port 8443
                     :join? false
                     :ssl? true
                     :keystore "./resources/keystore.jks"
                     :key-password "foo"})))
```

This config doesn't work, however, as the below log shows. But why?

#### Log

```
$ heroku logs --app foo-test
2017-02-02T23:11:42.161056+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-02-02T23:11:42.295501+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-02-02T23:11:43.413805+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-02-02 23:11:43.412:INFO::main: Logging initialized @10893ms
2017-02-02T23:11:43.520845+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-02-02 23:11:43.518:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.z-SNAPSHOT
2017-02-02T23:11:43.987674+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-02-02 23:11:43.986:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@29a6b0b2{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8443}
2017-02-02T23:11:43.989942+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-02-02 23:11:43.988:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED ServerConnector@31da0434{SSL-http/1.1}{0.0.0.0:443}: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
2017-02-02T23:11:43.989944+00:00 app[web.1]: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
2017-02-02T23:11:43.989945+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.989945+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.989946+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.989948+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.989947+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.989948+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:321)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.989949+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.989950+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.989951+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.989952+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:366)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.989953+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.989953+00:00 app[web.1]:    at ring.adapter.jetty$run_jetty.invokeStatic(jetty.clj:137)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.989954+00:00 app[web.1]:    at ring.adapter.jetty$run_jetty.invoke(jetty.clj:100)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.989954+00:00 app[web.1]:    at foo.server$_main.invokeStatic(server.clj:9)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.989955+00:00 app[web.1]:    at foo.server$_main.doInvoke(server.clj:7)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.989956+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:397)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.989956+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:375)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.989957+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:152)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.989958+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.989959+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.main$main_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:314)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.989958+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:646)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.989959+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.main$main_opt.invoke(main.clj:310)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.989961+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.main$main.invokeStatic(main.clj:421)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.989961+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:384)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.989962+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.989963+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.989963+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:383)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.989964+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.989967+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.991194+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-02-02 23:11:43.990:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@6e24ce51: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
2017-02-02T23:11:43.991195+00:00 app[web.1]: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
2017-02-02T23:11:43.991196+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.991197+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.991197+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.991198+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.991199+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.991200+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:321)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.991200+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.991201+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.991202+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.991203+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:366)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.991203+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.991204+00:00 app[web.1]:    at ring.adapter.jetty$run_jetty.invokeStatic(jetty.clj:137)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.991205+00:00 app[web.1]:    at ring.adapter.jetty$run_jetty.invoke(jetty.clj:100)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.991205+00:00 app[web.1]:    at foo.server$_main.invokeStatic(server.clj:9)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.991207+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:397)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.991206+00:00 app[web.1]:    at foo.server$_main.doInvoke(server.clj:7)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.991207+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:375)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.991208+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:152)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.991209+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:646)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.991209+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.991210+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.main$main_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:314)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.991211+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.main$main_opt.invoke(main.clj:310)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.991211+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.main$main.invokeStatic(main.clj:421)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.991212+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:384)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.991213+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:383)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.991213+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.991212+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.991214+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
2017-02-02T23:11:43.991218+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
2017-02-02T23:11:44.073981+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-02-02 23:11:44.073:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Stopped ServerConnector@29a6b0b2{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8443}
2017-02-02T23:11:44.095345+00:00 app[web.1]: Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
2017-02-02T23:11:44.074293+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-02-02 23:11:44.074:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Stopped ServerConnector@31da0434{SSL-http/1.1}{0.0.0.0:443}
2017-02-02T23:11:44.095700+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
2017-02-02T23:11:44.095798+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
2017-02-02T23:11:44.095861+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
2017-02-02T23:11:44.095958+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
2017-02-02T23:11:44.096022+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
2017-02-02T23:11:44.096113+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:321)
2017-02-02T23:11:44.096268+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236)
2017-02-02T23:11:44.096179+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
2017-02-02T23:11:44.096338+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
2017-02-02T23:11:44.096430+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:366)
2017-02-02T23:11:44.096495+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
2017-02-02T23:11:44.096585+00:00 app[web.1]:    at ring.adapter.jetty$run_jetty.invokeStatic(jetty.clj:137)
2017-02-02T23:11:44.096727+00:00 app[web.1]:    at foo.server$_main.invokeStatic(server.clj:9)
2017-02-02T23:11:44.096649+00:00 app[web.1]:    at ring.adapter.jetty$run_jetty.invoke(jetty.clj:100)
2017-02-02T23:11:44.096808+00:00 app[web.1]:    at foo.server$_main.doInvoke(server.clj:7)
2017-02-02T23:11:44.096872+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:397)
2017-02-02T23:11:44.096962+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:375)
2017-02-02T23:11:44.097025+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:152)
2017-02-02T23:11:44.097112+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
2017-02-02T23:11:44.097671+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:646)
2017-02-02T23:11:44.097769+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.main$main_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:314)
2017-02-02T23:11:44.097834+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.main$main_opt.invoke(main.clj:310)
2017-02-02T23:11:44.097908+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.main$main.invokeStatic(main.clj:421)
2017-02-02T23:11:44.097989+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:384)
2017-02-02T23:11:44.098056+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
2017-02-02T23:11:44.098147+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:383)
2017-02-02T23:11:44.098312+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
2017-02-02T23:11:44.098210+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
2017-02-02T23:11:44.098419+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
2017-02-02T23:11:44.314609+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-02-02T23:12:07.539455+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=foo-test.herokuapp.com request_id=dff25101-ab3c-4464-ac06-d0e5a9586797 fwd="107.3.128.7" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: If this is running on Heroku, you may not need to implement HTTPS yourself. Heroku handles SSL termination for *.herokuapp.com, and its included for custom domains on paid dynos https://blog.heroku.com/ssl-is-now-included-on-all-paid-dynos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`:port` is for http 
`:ssl-port` is for https

https://ring-clojure.github.io/ring/ring.adapter.jetty.html

You are getting permission denied because it is trying to bind to the default SSL port **443** which you need **sudo** access for ports less than **1024**

```
2017-02-02T23:11:43.987674+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-02-02 23:11:43.986:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@29a6b0b2{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8443}
2017-02-02T23:11:43.989942+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-02-02 23:11:43.988:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED ServerConnector@31da0434{SSL-http/1.1}{0.0.0.0:443}: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
```

Notice `{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8443}` successfully binds per your configuration 
while `{SSL-http/1.1}{0.0.0.0:443}` fails

Comment: This is useful information for running _any_ service on ports less than 1024.

Answer (score 0):

Your `-main` rather suspiciously ignores its port environment variable. You parse it, and then ignore it and use 8443 regardless.

Comment: Very true. This is because I was still in the process of figuring out how the configuration actually needed to be, before I set up environment variables for that configuration.